# C# find the path between different button color

Tags: c#, algorithm

The board has 10 row and 10 Column buttons all Green color. The board randomly generates 9 red color obstacles. My question is how to find the path (changing the green color to white color)starting from entry to exit going horizontally and vertically using only the Green color button.Every time when i hit Go button the green button will change in to white.The program only find one path at a time. for example the first path execute on (2(10)-1) then when i hit Go button again it will find another path. This will  continue until all the green button changing in to white. btn 1 is the entry and btn 100 is the exit. i use the click event .....?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99;)
{

    string btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i+10);
    var btn_now = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];

    btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
    var btn_next = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];
    var btn_below = btn_next;



    if (i <= 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90)
    {
        btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i);
        btn_below = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];
    }
    if(btn_next.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) {

        if (i <= 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90)
            i+= 1;
        else
            i++;
       btn_now = btn_next;
    }
    else {
        btn_now = btn_next;
        i+=1;                    
    }
    btn_now.BackColor = Color.White;

}
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the logic behind your code... like what is the point of << if (i <= 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90)
            i+= 1;
        else
            i++; >> (both +=1 and i++ do the same...)

Comment: You need to find a path or the shortest path?

Comment: Probably best to look into  A* search algorithm, which works by evaluating every possible path and finding the path with the lowest cost. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Example

Comment: yes first the shortest path then all path.. i think A* search algorithm maybe help thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need A* for 100 cells.

The algorithm I used was roughly this:

Assign the "exit" cell a "distance" of 0, add it to "visited" list
Foreach cell in "visited", add unvisited neighbours to the "visited" list with distance + 1
Repeat until entry the cell is found or no new cells are found

At this point we have a list of cells and their distance from the exit. Return null if we didn't find the entry point.

Create an empty list, "path", and add the entry cell. Then, starting from the entry cell, look for a neighbour with a "distance" 1 less than the current cell. Add this cell to our path and repeat until we find the exit.

We then have a shortest path. (To find all shortest paths, look for all neighbours with a "distance" 1 less than the current cell and either copy your current path or use a more complicated structure than a list to store path(s)).

This algorithm is implemented, in javascript, on this webpage.

http://eastereggs.azurewebsites.net/eastereggs

Comment: Thank you so much! i almost quit this project. i understand the logic but my question is bool i use for all the button and add in different list (visited and unvisited list) or how do i know the button is visited or not....?